# (PowerPC) Do not understand why the code stores contents of registers in the same address

Tags: assembly, powerpc, xbox360

I recently started reversing the game for the Xbox 360, and I really don’t understand why the contents of %r11 and %r10 are stored in the addresses [%r8] and [%r9] that have the same address (0x00010000).

This code generated by IDA.

```
.globl _start
_start:

.set var_1F0, -0x1F0

.long_zero: .long 0
.long_zero_1: .long 0

mflr    %r12            # Move from link register
bl      sub_831A8168    # Branch
addi    %r31, %sp, var_1F0 # Add Immediate
stwu    %sp, -0x1F0(%sp) # Store Word with Update
nop                     # No Operation
# -------------------------------------------------------------|
mr      %r8, %r8        # Move Register
mr      %r8, %r8        # Move Register
lis     %r9, ((long_zero+0x10000)@h) # Load Immediate Shifted
lis     %r8, ((long_zero_1+0x10000)@h) # Load Immediate Shifted
li      %r11, -1        # Load Immediate
li      %r10, -1        # Load Immediate
stw     %r11, long_zero@l(%r9) # Store Word
stw     %r10, long_zero_1@l(%r8) # Store Word
# -------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Comment: They are stored to different addresses because one uses `long_zero@l` as the offset and the other uses `long_zero_1@l` as the offset.

Comment: Do you mean that instead ```long_zero@l(%r9)``` will be ```address of long_zero + 0 + [%r9]```?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I undestand you correctly, your problem are the following two lines:

```
lis     %r9, ((long_zero+0x10000)@h)
...
stw     %r11, long_zero@l(%r9)
```

Let's assume that the word `long_zero` is located at the address `0x1234ABCD`:

`(xxx)@h` means: The high 16 bits of `(xxx)`.

`0x1234ABCD + 0x10000` is `0x1235ABCD` and the high 16 bits of this number are `0x1235`.

Therefore, the instruction `lis %r9, ((long_zero+0x10000)@h)` is equal to `lis %r9, 0x1235` and will load the value `0x12350000` into register `r9`.

`xxx@l` means: The low 16 bits of `xxx`.

For this reason `stw %r11, long_zero@l(%r9)` is equal to `stw %r11, 0xABCD(%r9)`.

This instruction will sign-extend `0xABCD` (to `0xFFFFABCD`) and add the sign-extended value to the value in register `r9`; the result is the address being written: `0x12350000 + 0xFFFFABCD = 0x1234ABCD`.

By the way: I assume that the first instruction was not `lis %r9, ((long_zero+0x10000)@h)` but `lis %r9, long_zero@ha` before being assembled.

`@ha` assumes that the low 16 bits will be sign-extended and the result will be added to the register in a later (here: `stw`) instruction.

This means that `xxx@ha` is equal to `xxx@h` if bit 15 of `xxx` is 0 (so the low 16 bits represent a positive number) and it is equal to `(xxx+0x10000)@h` if bit 15 is 1 (so the low 16 bits represent a negative number).

Comment: why positive number ```0xABCD``` extends to ```0xFFFFABCD```? Shouldn't it be ```0x0000ABCD``` because of positive numbers start with 0 and negative with 1 in binary form?

Comment: @AkmubiLin `0xABCD` would be **1**010101111001101 in binary form. So the first bit is a "1". Please note that you have to know the number of bits to judge if a number is positive or negative. The 16-bit number `0xABC` would be positive; the 12-bit number `0xABC` would be negative. PowerPC instructions normally take 16-bit numbers.